# Locally Euclidean topology - but not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, analysis

We consider the set $X=\mathbb{R}\cup \{\star\}$, i.e. $X$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$ and an additional point $\star$.

We say that $U\subset X$ is open if:

(a) For each point $x\in U\cap \mathbb{R}$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\subset U$.

(b) If $\star \in U$ then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon , 0)\cup (0, \epsilon)\subset U$.
$$$$

1. Show that this defines a topology in $X$.
2. Show that $X$ with this topology is locally Euclidean but not Hausdorff.
   $$$$

For (1) we have to show that $X$ and $\emptyset$ are open, the union of two open sets is open and the intersection of two open sets is open.

First we show that $X$ is open :

(a) For each point $x\in X\cap \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\subset X=\mathbb{R}\cup \{\star\}$. This is true since every neighboorhood of $x$ is contained.

(b) If $\star \in X$ then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon , 0)\cup (0, \epsilon)\subset X=\mathbb{R}\cup \{\star\}$. Thisis true since the union of the intervals is a subspace of the real line.

Is that correct?

The emptyset is per definition open, or not? We don’t have to apply the given definition, do we?

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two open sets. We consider the union $M_1\cup M_2$. For each point $x\in M_1\cup M_2$ it is either $x\in M_1$ or $x\in M_2$ (or both) so statement (a) follows from the fact that $M_1$ and/or $M_2$ are open. The same holds also for statement (b).

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two open sets. We consider the intersection $M_1\cap M_2$. For each point $x\in M_1\cap M_2$ it is $x\in M_1$ and $x\in M_2$ so statement (a) follows from the fact that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are open. The same holds also for statement (b).

Therefore we get that the above defines a topology in $X$.

Is that correct and complete?

Could you give a hint for (2) ?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in (b).

Comment: It isn't sufficient to show that the union of 2 open sets is open. You need arbitrary unions.

Comment: I think (b) should be the following: If $\star \in U$, then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$, such that $(-\varepsilon,0)\cup\{\star\}\cup(0,\varepsilon) \subseteq X$.
For (2), you need to show that $\{ U \cap \mathbb{R} \mid U \in \mathcal{O}_X\} = \mathcal{O}_E$, where $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the topology on $X$, i.e. the set of sets that you described in (a) and (b), and $\mathcal{O}_E$ is the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @jasnee The version of (b) as written implies your version, because if $\star \in U$ then there are two conclusions to be made: first that $\{\star\} \subset U$; and then from (b) as written we obtain $(-\epsilon,0) \cup (0,\epsilon) \subset U$ for some $\epsilon > 0$; it follows that $(-\epsilon,0) \cup \{\star\} \cup (0,\epsilon) \subset U$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, thanks for pointing that out! But OP should still write $\cup$ instead of $\cap$ in their definition in (b), right?

Comment: Ah, that's funny, I didn't see that. Yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Yes, you are right! In (b) there is union instead of intersection.

Comment: In the Euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}$, the open sets are the unions of open intervals, right? So do we have to write the statements of (a) and (b) inthe formof open intervals? @jasnee

Comment: So do we have to show that the union of an arbitrary number of open sets is open? @GiorgosGiapitzakis

Comment: An arbitrary **family** of open sets is open. This family doesn't have to be finite or even countable.

Comment: Ok! But how do we do that in this case? Do we say the same as I did above but instead of the union of two sets we take the union of a family of open sets? @GiorgosGiapitzakis

Comment: @MaryStar You don't necessarily need to do that. You simply want to show both inclusions to get equality, it's fairly straightforward. It helps to just think in terms of standard open intervals, with an additional "annoying" point $\star$, which you'll have to work around, but it's all possible without too much effort.

Comment: Could you explain to me further what we have to show? I got stuck right now. @jasnee

Comment: How could we improve the proof of (1)? I edited a little my approach... How could I change that that this holds for any arbitrary union? @GiorgosGiapitzakis

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof of part (2): Using your definition of open sets in $X$, we denote with $\mathcal{O}_X$ the topology on $X$, i.e. the set of open sets in $X$. Let $\mathcal{O}_E$ denote the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$. To show that $X$ is locally Euclidean we'll want to show that $$\{U' \cap \mathbb{R} \mid U' \in \mathcal{O}_X \} = \mathcal{O}_E$$ (you can take a look at [this page](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Locally_Euclidean_space), if you want to verify that this is indeed what we need to show).

($\subseteq$) Let $U \in \{U' \cap \mathbb{R} \mid U \in \mathcal{O}_X \}$, i.e. $U = U' \cap \mathbb{R}$ with $U' \in \mathcal{O}_X$. If $U'$ consists only of numbers in $\mathbb{R}$, it is automatically contained in $\mathcal{O}_E$, so in particular $U \in \mathcal{O}_E$. If $U'$ is a neighborhood of $\star$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(-\varepsilon,0) \cup \{\star\} \cup (0,\varepsilon) \subseteq U'$. So we have $(-\varepsilon,0) \cup (0,\varepsilon) \subseteq U' \cap \mathbb{R} = U$, so $U\in \mathcal{O}_E$ (because again we have shown that every point in $U$ is contained within an open set).

($\supseteq$) Let $U \in \mathcal{O}_E$, i.e. for all $a \in U$ there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon) \subseteq U$. So we have $U \in \{U' \cap \mathbb{R} \mid U' \in \mathcal{O}_X \}$.

Thus we have shown both inclusions, and equality follows. Hope this helps!

**Edit**: Sorry, forgot about the Hausdorff part. To show that $X$ is not Hausdorff, look at neighborhoods of $0$ and $\star$. For a neighborhood $U_0$ of $0$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \subseteq U_0$. For a neighborhood $U_\star$ of $\star$, there exists $\varepsilon' > 0$ such that $(-\varepsilon',0) \cup \{\star\} \cup (0,\varepsilon') \subseteq U_\star$. However, their intersection is non-empty, since
\begin{align}
(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \cap \big((-\varepsilon',0) \cup \{\star\} \cup (0,\varepsilon')\big) &= (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \cap \big((-\varepsilon',0) \cup (0,\varepsilon')\big)\\
&= \big((-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \cap (-\varepsilon',0)\big) \cup \big((-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \cap (0,\varepsilon')\big) \neq \emptyset,
\end{align}
so $X$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Greatl! Thank you for the explanation!! Could you take  a look also at the first part of the question, (1)? Is that correct how I showed that a topology is defined?

Comment: @MaryStar (1) is fine, except for the part where you show that the union of two open sets is open. You must show that an arbitrary union of open sets is open, so in particular  infinite unions. However, the proof should be similar to what you have already done in the case of two open sets.
Also, in your proof that finite intersections are open, you could be more specific: since $x$ is contained in $M_1$ and $M_2$, you get an $\varepsilon_1>0$ and $\varepsilon_2>0$. Then define $\varepsilon := \text{min}(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2)$. This new interval is contained in $M_1 \cap M_2$.

Comment: What do we have to change to get that an arbitrary union of open sets is open? Do we just have to add something in words to get that? Or do we have to change something at the symbols?

Comment: @MaryStar You simply start your sentence with "Let $\{M_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of open subsets in $X$, where $I$ is an arbitrary index set". Then your goal is to show that $\bigcup_{i \in I} M_i$ is an open set in $X$. But this follows from a similar argument as in the case where you chose the index set $I=\{1,2\}$ in your pseudo-proof above. So all in all, you had basically already done all the work. This was just a technicality.